# Реализовать конвейер linux

Tags: linux, c

Пытаюсь реализовать конвейер на си. Аргументы передаются из терминала. Например: ./program.out ls cat wc должно отработать как ls | cat | wc и любые другие конвейеры. На количество команд ограничение не стоит. Данный код работает для ls wc или ls wc wc, но для вышепривеенных примеров не работает. Как исправить ситуацию, а еще лучше использовать вместое system: execve или execvp.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int pipedes[2];

int main (unsigned int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]) {

  pid_t pid;
  int i;
  char *argvs[] = { 0, NULL};

     if (argc < 3) {
        printf ("usage: %s prog1 prog2\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
        }

    for(i = 1; i < argc - 1; i++){
      pipe(pipedes);
    if (pid=fork()){
      argvs[0]=argv[i];
      dup2 (pipedes[1], 1);
      close (pipedes[0]);
      execvp (argvs[0], argvs);
    }
    else{
      argvs[0] = argv[i + 1];
      dup2 (pipedes[0], 0);
      close (pipedes[1]);
      system(argvs[0]);
    }


    }
  close (pipedes[0]);
      close (pipedes[1]);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: По крайней мере вам нужно иметь `n - 1` массивов `pipedes[2]` (n это количество команд конвейера) и правильно делать dup во всех потомках (в первом оставлять родной stdin, в последнем stdout, в остальных dup-ать оба)

Comment: Я в цикле вызываю pipe он же и гарантирует мне n-1 массивов. Как раз команды идут от argv[1]. А вот по поводу стандартного в/в не очень понятно

Comment: Да, без n - 1 массивов можно обойтись, переиспользуя старые переменные в новых процессах, но для каждого процесса в середине конвейера нужно 2 пайпа. К одному цепляете stdin, ко второму stdout. Ну,  время уже позднее, если сами или кто-нибудь еще на днях не сделает, а у меня будет время и желание, то тряхну стариной и напишу код.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь) мне на завтра))) Попробую сам тогда)

Comment: Успехов (не скучной ночи -)). Вообще, приходит в голову не явно программировать цикл, а заменить его цепочкой fork-ов со сдвигом argv. Т.е. каждый элемент конвейера программирует своего потомка, переключает свой stdout (fd = 1), а потомок наследует пайп и переключает свой stdin (fd = 0)/ Соответственно последний свой stdout не переключит, а у первого останется родной stdin/ Но, это отличается от классического конвейера, т.к. первоначальный parent может ждать завершения только первого процесса в конвейере, а не всех.

Comment: Уже сделал) Спасибо за помощь, кода стало меньше чем приведенный выше, при желании если убрать проверки на ошибки, там 15 строк кода не больше) Чуть позже время появится выкину в сеть потомкам на будущее:D Время 4 утра еще дела есть=)

Comment: Ключевое слово: `if (isatty()) ...` [тыц](http://www.c-cpp.ru/content/isatty)

Comment: Молодец, @StenFord! А код лучше всего выложить сюда, в качестве самоответа (это не возбраняется и даже приветствуется)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пожалуй, больше всего меня заинтересовала не заданная явно в вопросе задача, а именно, *как в цикле запуска команд конвейера можно определить, успешно ли выполнена `execvp()`?*

Вот что получилось:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <signal.h>

#include <limits.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <string.h>


// in *nix I trust (if /proc/<PID>/stat exists it's format is valid)
static void
get_proc_stat_name (FILE *fs, char *cbuf)
{
  int c;

  while ((c = fgetc(fs)) != '(');

  while ((c = fgetc(fs)) != ')')
    *cbuf++ = c;
  *cbuf = 0;

}

// returns 0, if exec() in `pid` process failed
static int
check_exec (pid_t pid, struct stat *parent, const char *p_name)
{
  struct stat st;

  char cbuf[PATH_MAX]; /* yes, I’m being cheap ("жаба душит") -) */
  snprintf(cbuf, PATH_MAX, "/proc/%d/exe", (int)pid);

  do {
    if (stat(cbuf, &st)) { // now zombie (realy, the /proc/<PID>/exe is link to not existing file)
      snprintf(cbuf, PATH_MAX, "/proc/%d/stat", (int)pid);
      FILE *fs = fopen(cbuf, "r");
      if (!fs)
        exit((perror(cbuf), -1));

      get_proc_stat_name(fs, cbuf);
      fclose(fs);

      if (strcmp(p_name, cbuf) == 0)
        return 1; // exec() was successful and command already completed
      break;
    }
    if (parent->st_ino != st.st_ino || parent->st_dev != st.st_dev) // change, so exec() OK
      return 1;

    // exec() still not called
  } while (sched_yield() == 0);

  return 0;
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  if (ac < 3)
    exit((puts("Usage: ./a.out p1 p2 ..."), 1));

  pid_t pid;
  int pfd[2], input;
  struct stat st;
  stat("/proc/self/exe", &st);

  // этот цикл, собственно, решение задачи в вопросе -- запуск конвейера команд 
  for (int i = 1; i < ac; i++) {
    pipe(pfd);

    if (!(pid = fork())) {
      //      printf("child %d of %d grp %d\n", (int)getpid(), (int)getppid(), (int)getpgrp());

      if (i != 1) {      // first command read inhereted stdin
        dup2(input, 0);  //   any other read pfd[0] from previous iteration
        close(input);
      }
      if (i != ac - 1)   // last command write to inhereted stdout
        dup2(pfd[1], 1); //   any other write to current pfd[1]
      close(pfd[0]);
      close(pfd[1]);

      char *argv [2] = {av[i], NULL};
      execvp(av[i], argv);
      fprintf(stderr, "command `%s` not found, terminate\n", av[i]);
      exit(-1);
    }

    //    printf("fork to %d\n", (int)pid);
    //puts(">>>"); getchar();

    if (i != 1)
      close(input);
    close(pfd[1]);
    input = pfd[0];  // the next member of commands pipe will read this fd

    // Well,  the icing on the cake
    if (!check_exec(pid, &st, av[i]))
      killpg(getpgrp(), SIGTERM);
  }

  close(input);

  while ((pid = wait(0)) != -1);
    //    printf("fin: %d\n", pid);

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}

/*
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ ./a.out tty od wc md5sum
01500bbe0759d9a8570c04246d152099  -
End
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ tty|od|wc|md5sum
01500bbe0759d9a8570c04246d152099  -
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ 
*/
```

Идея решения строится на следующих фактах:

- файл `/proc/<PID>/exe` (это символьный линк на исполняемый файл) после выполнения `exec()` меняется
- для завершившегося процесса этот  линк указывает "в никуда"
- у уже завершившегося процесса (зомби) в файле `/proc/<PID>/stat` сохраняется имя, под которым он работал (значение `argv[0]` в `exec()`)
- информация для зомби в `/proc/` после `wait()` в родителе более не существует.

Вполне вероятно, что существует более простое (эффективное) решение, так что, буду рад любым адекватным комментариям.

Надеюсь, что для пользы изучающим программирование я оставил закомментированную в "точках отладки" печать.

P.S.
`bash` при запуске команд в конвейере этим не заморачивается (видимо для этого есть разумные причины), каждая следующая команда запускается независимо от того, существует ли  предыдущая.